# Spring boot - A bean with that name has already been defined and overriding is disabled

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-bean

I am building a Spring-Boot applciation which uses a Mongo database repository, defined as below:

```
package com.example.repository;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example..model.UserProfile;

@Repository
public interface UserProfileRepository extends MongoRepository<UserProfile, Double> {
    
    Optional<UserProfile> findByEmail(String email);

    Boolean existsByEmail(String email);
  
}
```

Without importing/autowiring the repository in any other classes, when I try to run the spring application I am immediately hit with:

> Description:
>
> The bean 'userProfileRepository' could not be registered. A bean with
> that name has already been defined and overriding is disabled.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting
> spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

If I simply remove the repository class and run the application everything is fine.

Update:

Stack trace after running with --debug

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'userProfileRepository' defined in null: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] for bean 'userProfileRepository': There is already [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] bound.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:927) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:175) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.java:107) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$1(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:385) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:384) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:148) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:337) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:242) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at com.example.ExampleApplication.main(SpringSocialApplication.java:13) [classes/:na]
```

Comment: You probably have it defined somewhere else in your code.  Search for "UserProfileRepository" and see if your code has it defined somewhere else :)

Comment: I've exhausted that already. It's definitely defined nowhere else - the issue goes away if this class is removed, and the error is still there if I rename (without refactor) the class

Comment: Remove the `@Repository` it is useless. If that doesn't solve it run the app with --debug which will give you a stracktrace to inform you what is wrong.

Comment: Tried without @Repository - same issue. Have added stack trace output from running with --debug to original post. This seems to be an issue relating to org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository. I tried switching to org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository and pointing to a MySQL database and it ran with no issues.

Comment: @nick_j_white have you used the `@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.your.repository.package")`?

Comment: I did initially add `@EnableMongoRepositories({ "com.example.repository" })` to every class where userProfileRepository was autowired, but when the error first hit I removed every reference in all other classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
basePackages = {"com.abc.searchengine.repo"}
```

Add above line to yourprojectApplication.java file. See example below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.abc.searchengine.repo"})
public class SearchEngineApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SearchEngineApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when in config file(in my case SpringBootApplication file) I defined a class, say, `A` as a bean(@Bean) say:

```
 ....
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context=SpringApplication.run(RTGApp.class, args);
 ....
 }
 @Bean
 public A a(){
  return new A();
 }
}
```

and in its own A file put *@Component* over the definition :
@Component
class A{}
Because @Component contains that @Bean.
Thus it got created twice.
Therefore, I must remove either the `@Component` annotation or the whole `@Bean a()` method

Comment: The eleven years old answer saved my day. Thanks